# Can I publish a VS Code Extension to the VS Code Marketplace if the source code of the extension is in a private Github repo?

Tags: vscode-extensions

A customer of mine wants to publish their first VS Code extension. Right now, they use a private repo. Neither they nor I managed to find VS Code publishing policy information that addresses whether they can use their private repo or use a public one.

Could anyone point out an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `vsce package` to generate the VSIX file.
2. Register a Marketplace account and upload the VSIX file from the web portal.

Comment: Sorry for refusing your answer; my question is about whether the VS Code publishing policy allows publishing extensions with a private repo or not.

Comment: @IstvanNovak A TypeScript/JavaScript based extension does not hide any secret actually. There are tons of Microsoft or non Microsoft extensions shipping private (non open source) binaries in various ways. So I doubt anyone or any policy prevents you from doing the same.

Comment: Thanks, @Lex Li. Your answer seems to confirm that no such *declared* policy exists.

Answer (score 1):

Once the extension is packed all code is in it, so it is not necessary to have a public Github repo (or any repo at all). Simply don't specify the `repository` key in your package.json file.

Comment: Thanks, @Mike Lischke!